# Stop Copy Task immediately if one file was not copied successfully

Tags: deployment, msbuild, msbuild-task

Just imagine regular `Deploy Target` which copies thousand files to the remote network folder using [MSBuild Copy Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx), I believe pretty common scenario. So when folder is not accessible or there are some access privilegies problems - obviously Copy Task would not be able to copy files, but it will try to copy each file anyway, I want to prevent this to speed up Deploy Target for this case and report `Failed` status immediately and do not wait 30-60 mins whilst it process all files in the queue...

How to force `MSBuild` Copy Task to stop immediately in case when a file was not copied successfully and do not try to copy all other files?
If this is not possible using Copy Task perhaps this could be achieved using other facilities?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Exec task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) instead. Like this:

```
<Exec Command="xcopy /s &#34;from with spaces&#34; $(WebDeployFolder)\$(WebDeployName)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be better to use robocopy to copy, its has a plenty of options for similar things. See the task in the extension pack:
http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.4.0/index.html

The options property of the task takes a number of parameters:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: I've found only `/r:<N>` which allows specifying retris count, but as far as I understand this applies to each not-copied file, but I need terminate entire job as soon as first file was not copied